# Retrieve POST data sent with Guzzle (6.3) from Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I am posting some data from my laravel app to another plain PHP page I have on my local server. The status code returned by Guzzle says it was successful but I am unable to access it. How can I do this?

I've tried using the Post method to retrieve value but no luck

Guzzle Function:

```php
$client = new Client();
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'http://localhost/testApp/guzTest.php',
        [
            'form_params' => [
                'amnt' =>  75
            ],
            'allow_redirects' => true
        ]);
    echo $response->getStatusCode();
```

Page Receiving POST DATA:

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST['amnt'])) {
        echo $_POST['amnt'];
    }else
        echo 'not found';   
?>
```

I expect to be able to access the amount posted via post method but nothing is yielded.

Comment: Please do confirm which version of guzzle you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try somthing like that .

```
 $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'http://localhost/testApp/guzTest.php',
        [
            'form_params' => [
                'amnt' =>  75
            ],
            'allow_redirects' => true
        ]);

$contents = $response->getBody()->getContents();
$contents = json_decode($contents,true);

return ($contents);
```

On page Receiving POST DATA:
Response should be like this

```
  return response()->json([
            'status' => 'SUCCESS',
            'code' => '200',
        ], 200);
```